# Image Loading From Google Drive Spreadsheet Android

Tags: android, image, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So I have an app where I'm loading the data from GDrive spreadsheet and the content is user info(name,some info and image).Everything is OK except this I can't get the image because in the image row I have link to the image who looks like this https://docs.google.com/a/mentormate.com/file/d/0BzkDNB0JekTGN1FtZVZrRl9WaDg/edit .What I need is information of how to open this file and get the image so I can load it on my ImageView in the app.Here's example of what I've so far.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final viewHolder h;
    Person p = users.get(i);

    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_user, viewGroup, false);
        h = new viewHolder();

        h.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        h.position = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.position);
        h.picture = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);

        v.setTag(h);
    } else {
        h = (viewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    h.name.setText(p.getName());
    h.position.setText(p.getPosition());


    AsdImageLoader.displayImage(p.getPicture(), h.picture);
```

and displayImage() method:

```
public static void displayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    ImageLoader.getInstance()
        .displayImage(url, imageView, mDisplayOptions);
}
```

p.getPicture() is returning me the link from above that I gave as example.
Thanks in advance for the help!